# How to use autocompletion from textfield in iphone?

Tags: iphone, autocomplete

In iPhone,  Autocompletion for message typing purpose in textfield, type a message like  "iph" visible a placeholder in background of the text like "one". How to make this? please any one help me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a delegate on your text field.  In the delegate, override `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`.  That's where you can look at what the user has typed and is about to type and decide what autocompletion text to display.